# Taxonomy Archive with same rewrite slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom post type and a taxonomy assigned to it. I'm having a problem setting up my pretty permalinks to behave like below:

1. /custom-post-type/

   - Displays all posts in that cpt **(works fine)**
2. /custom-post-type/post-title

   - Display the post **(works fine)**
3. /custom-post-type/categories/

   - Display all terms in my taxonomy registered to 'custom-post-type' ***(does not work)***
4. /custom-post-type/categories/term-name

   - display all posts with that term-name **(works fine)**

**snippet for taxonomy**

`'hierarchical' => true,
 'query_var' => false,
 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-post-type/categories', 'with_front' => false)`

**snippet for CPT**

`'query_var' => true,
 'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'custom-post-type'),
 'has_archive' => 'custom-post-type'`

**What Happens:**
When I hit the 3rd permalink, i get a 404 because WP is looking for a post named 'category' in that custom post type. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Working this problem over now.